# Apply an image on cube faces - VTK

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vtk

I use VTK on visual studio 2010, I would like apply an image on the cube faces.

Code to read my image :

```
// Read JPG image
vtkSmartPointer<vtkJPEGReader> JPEGReader = vtkSmartPointer<vtkJPEGReader>::New();
JPEGReader->SetFileName(argv[1]);
JPEGReader->Update();

// Image actor
vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageActor> imageActor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageActor>::New();
imageActor->GetMapper()->SetInputData(JPEGReader->GetOutput());
```

Setup cube code :

```
// Setup cube
vtkSmartPointer<vtkCubeSource> cubeSource = vtkSmartPointer<vtkCubeSource>::New();
cubeSource->Update();
vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper> cubeMapper = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper>::New();
cubeMapper->SetInputConnection(cubeSource->GetOutputPort());
vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor> cubeActor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>::New();
cubeActor->SetMapper(cubeMapper);
cubeActor->GetProperty()->SetDiffuseColor(.3, .6, .4);
```

How I do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a texture and a texture map to achieve what you want. I adapted a small example from [this](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Python/Visualization/SphereTexture) one (although in python) that can help you with a starting point. In this case, `vtkTextureMapToPlane` is not the ideal one, because it only covers 2 faces of the cube (check out the image below). However, I think `vtkTextureMapToBox`, as in [this](http://poseidon.csd.auth.gr/New_Courses/graphics_back/vtk/manhtml/vtkTextureMapToBox.html) link, should be able to do the trick (I could not use it because I am using VTK 5.8).

Code:

```
import vtk

# Create a render window
ren = vtk.vtkRenderer()
renWin = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
renWin.AddRenderer(ren)
renWin.SetSize(480,480)
iren = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
iren.SetRenderWindow(renWin)

# Generate a cube 
cube = vtk.vtkCubeSource()

# Read the image data from a file
reader = vtk.vtkJPEGReader()
reader.SetFileName("yourimage.jpg")

# Create texture object
texture = vtk.vtkTexture()
texture.SetInputConnection(reader.GetOutputPort())

#Map texture coordinates
map_to_plane = vtk.vtkTextureMapToPlane()
map_to_plane.SetInputConnection(cube.GetOutputPort())

# Create mapper and set the mapped texture as input
mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
mapper.SetInputConnection(map_to_plane.GetOutputPort())

# Create actor and set the mapper and the texture
actor = vtk.vtkActor()
actor.SetMapper(mapper)
actor.SetTexture(texture)

ren.AddActor(actor)

iren.Initialize()
renWin.Render()
iren.Start()
```

Result:

[image]